# CSS :hover and :active with internal element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a sortable list using jQueryUI, when the user hovers over a list item I would like to present a group of options (edit, delete, etc.) - up to this point everything is working ok.

The bit I am having trouble with is that I would like the options to disappear when a list item becomes active (before the user attempts to move it to a new location).

I sort of have this working however I can no longer click the button - when I click the button the list item becomes active and hides the options.

I think this may be the issue:

```
    .script-item:active .scriptItemOptions {
        display: none;
    }
```

Am I going about this the right way?

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59uhw3j6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule is your problem, yes. The `:active` pseudo class refer to the exact moment when the user is clicking in an element. So when the user try to click your element, the `.scriptItemOptions` is hidden.

But when you click on the `scriptItemOptions`, the `script-item` is active too ! Because `scriptItemOptions` is a child of the `script-item`

I edited your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/59uhw3j6/2/
You can click the button now. I just added this rule :

```
.script-item:active .scriptItemOptions:active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to overwrite it with `!important`

```
.script-item:active .scriptItemOptions {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**[See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59uhw3j6/3/)**